# Define an XML element that must be empty and has no attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

I needed to define an XML element that has no sub-elements or any content at all, and has no attributes.

This is what I am doing:

```
<xs:element name="myEmptyElement" type="_Empty"/>
<xs:complexType name="_Empty">
</xs:complexType>
```

This appears to work fine, but I have to wonder if there is a way to do this without having to declare a complex type. Also, if there is anything wrong with what I have, please let me know.

*Anticipating that someone might be curious why I would need such an element: It is for a SOAP operation that does not require any parameter values.*

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**(1) You could avoid defining a named `xs:complexType`:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="myEmptyElement">
    <xs:complexType/>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**(2) You could use a `xs:simpleType` instead of a `xs:complexType`:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="myEmptyElement">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="0"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**(3) You could use `fixed=""` <sup><sub>[credit: [@Nemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768469/nemo)]</sub></sup>:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="myEmptyElement" type="xs:string" fixed=""/>
</xs:schema>
```

**(4) But note that if you avoid saying anything about the content model:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="myEmptyElement"/>
</xs:schema>
```

**You'll be allowing any attributes on and any content in `myEmptyElement`.**

Comment: This is for a SOAP web service and I use soapUI to test. When soapUI automatically generates requests, it generates `<web:getServerInfo/>` for #1, but `<web:getServerInfo>?</web:getServerInfo>` for #2 & #3.

Comment: I wondered if something like #2 would be a way to use `xs:simpleType`, but it's ironic that it is more verbose than using `xs:complexType`. I also don't like that it is saying the content is a string, albeit an empty string.

Comment: I guess something like `<xs:element name="myEmptyElement" type="xs:empty"/>` was too much to ask for. Therefore, I will be going with #1. Since I have only one such element, it is not worth defining a named type.

Answer (score 4):

Another example could be:

```
<xs:complexType name="empty">
    <xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="myEmptyElement" type="empty>
```

or

```
<xs:element name="myEmptyElement">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value=""/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

or

```
<xs:element name="myEmptyElement">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```