# Getting namespace error when creating XSD for XML which has custom xsi:type element

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to create XSD for small XML which has default namespace as `<POSLog xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/">` in the root element. Under the root element there's `<object xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="A">` namespace as well with custom `xsi:type`. Following are the XML and XSDs.

### test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <POSLog xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/">
        <object xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="A">
            <elt1>test1</elt1>
            <elt2>test2</elt2>
            <elt3>test3</elt3>
        </object>
        <SequenceNumber xmlns:ns2="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" xmlns="">3</SequenceNumber>
    </POSLog>
```

### object.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" targetNamespace="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import schemaLocation="schema1.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="POSLog">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="object" />
                <xs:element ref="SequenceNumber" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### schema1.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="object">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="elt1" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="A">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="object">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="elt2" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="elt3" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="SequenceNumber" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
    <xs:element name="object" type="object" />
</xs:schema>
```

When I try to validate XSD I'm getting following error. The reason for that error because `<object>`  element is also trying to validate using default namespace.

> ERROR: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}schema': No matching
> global declaration available for the validation root.

My requirement is to generate valid XML Schemas for above sample XML.

Comment: Do you wish to change the XML or the XSD?

Comment: @kjhughes I cannot change the XML so I'm trying to generate a xsd for the sample XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust your XSDs to validate your XML:

1. Observe that `POSLog` and `object` are in the `"http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/"` namespace and `SequenceNumber` is in no namepace.
2. Therefore, group your definitions such that `POSLog` and `object` are in one XSD (`object.xsd`) and `SequenceNumber` is in another (`schema1.xsd`).
3. Redistribute your type definitions accordingly.

Below is a complete set of adjustments needed to your XSDs to validate your XML:

### Original XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<POSLog xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ object.xsd">
  <object xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="A">
    <elt1>test1</elt1>
    <elt2>test2</elt2>
    <elt3>test3</elt3>
  </object>
  <SequenceNumber xmlns:ns2="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" xmlns="">3</SequenceNumber>
</POSLog>
```

### object.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:ns2="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/"
           targetNamespace="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="schema1.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="POSLog">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="ns2:object" />
        <xs:element ref="SequenceNumber" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="object" type="ns2:object" />
  <xs:complexType name="object">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="elt1" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="A">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="ns2:object">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="elt2" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="elt3" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

### schema1.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="SequenceNumber" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for above error.

In the object.xsd I have added `elementFormDefault="qualified"` attribute as this and changed the element object type as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" targetNamespace="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import schemaLocation="schema1.xsd" />
    <xs:complexType name="A">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="elt1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="elt2" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="elt3" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="POSLog">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="object">          
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element ref="SequenceNumber" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: `elementFormDefault="unqualified"` is a [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758277/290085), but it had nothing to do with your error.  (Flip it back and you'll see your XML still validates.)  Your actual errors, as I [explained in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69430291/290085), were due to attempting to group components in disparate namespaces in the same XSD.  (Your posted error regarding `schema` element not found would only have been a validation misstep.)

Comment: The new `object.xsd` that you've posted here effectively does that by implicitly leaving an unreferenced `object` declaration in no namespace in the imported `schema1.xsd`.  I'd recommend you clean that up as I've [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69430291/290085).

Comment: Also, note that as you've defined `object` in the above XSD, it's not referencing your original type declaration.  It's actually [allowing any attributes and any content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20754138/290085).

Comment: @kjhughes Thank you very much for the explanation. I'm quite new to this area. I will try out your answer and let you know. :)